# Rails - Cant run any rake commands db is messed up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Everything was working fine yesterday and all of a sudden when i tried to run my server or run any rake tasks i get this error

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'myapp_development.key_value_stores' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM `key_value_stores`
```

I've tried google searching and searching on stackoverflow all morning and cant find a solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to  rollback your migration file (take backup of the  migration file will help while creating new ),

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=migrations's_version
```

and then try to restart the rails server.If you face same problem then with same migration number search in schema_migrations table in database delete that record and make new migration again.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a while but what i ended up doing

update xcode and update command line tools

uninstall then install mysql via homebrew

then i ended up manually removing my database folder in

usr/local/var/mysql/myapp

then i did a

rake:create

and then i just pulled my production database and copied it to my development database

rake db:backup_and_load

then I was up and running again

dont know which one of that fixed it specifically but thats what i did